# Matrix Multiplication: C-to-VFX

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication, intrinsics, avx

This code is supposed to multiply two square matrices and return result. This algorithm would loop over matrix one reading two cells at once and so on.

```
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < N/2; ++k) {
                        
            mat01 = mat1[i][k*2];
            mat11 = mat1[i][(k*2)+1];

            for (j = 0; j < N ; j++)
            {   
                int n = (mat01 * mat2[k * 2][j]);
                int m = (mat11 * mat2[(k * 2) + 1][j]);
                result[i][j] += n + m;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to trun it to VFX and here is my solution but it is not giving me the expected results.

```
    __m256i A1, A2, B1, B2, D, C1, C2;
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < N/2; ++k) {
            A1 = _mm256_set1_epi32(mat1[i][k*2]);
            A2 = _mm256_set1_epi32(mat1[i][(k * 2) + 1]);

            for (j = 0; j < N; j+=16)
            {
                B1 = _mm256_loadu_epi32((__m256i*) & mat2[k*2][j]);
                B2 = _mm256_loadu_epi32((__m256i*) & mat2[(k * 2) + 1][j]);

                D = _mm256_loadu_epi32((__m256i*) & result[i][j]);

                C1 = _mm256_mullo_epi32(A1, B1);
                C2 = _mm256_mullo_epi32(A1, B2);

                 D = _mm256_add_epi32(D, C1);
                 D = _mm256_add_epi32(D, C2);

                _mm256_storeu_epi32((__m128*) & result[i][j], D);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What is `_mm256_storeu_epi32`?

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu The matrix multiplication result

Comment: Why do you cast to `(__m128*)` when storing with `_mm256_storeu_epi32`? Also, you are increasing `j` by 16, but `__m256i` only holds 8 `int32` values.

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu `_mm256_storeu_epi32` was introduced by AVX512, many compilers will likely compile it to an AVX-compatible `vmovdqu m256, ymm`, though.